# Running node commands in Swift

Tags: node.js, swift, nstask

I'm trying to run nodejs commands using Swift in my OS X app.

Running commands like echo work but when I'm trying to run node:

```
func node(args: String...) -> Int32 {
  let task = NSTask()
  task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
  task.arguments = args
  task.launch()
  task.waitUntilExit()
  return task.terminationStatus
}

node("/usr/local/bin/myscript")
node("node")
```

`node("/usr/local/bin/myscript")` is a scriptinstalled via `npm install -g myscript`

Comment: You don't mention what exactly doesn't work. Any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
node("node", "/usr/local/bin/myscript")
```

So that `env` starts the `node` program, with your script as a parameter to `node`.